# Adding views to the current viewcontroller from another class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController named MainViewController. I have an another class named ViewMaker.
 In the ViewMaker class I have a function as follows.

```
 -(UIView *)GetContentView
{
UIView *return_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];

UIButton *done_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
done_button.frame = CGRectMake(300, 300, 100, 50);
[done_button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[return_view addSubview:done_button];
return return_view;
}
```

In the above function actually I will add more views like textviews, labels etc.

In the MainViewController class I am calling the above method as follows.

```
 -(void)CreateViews
 {   
 UIView *content_view = [[[ViewMaker alloc] init] GetContentView];
 [self.view addSubview:content_view];
 }
```

Now I have added a view with done button(and other components like textviews, labels etc) from the MainViewController class.
My problem is about adding a target function for the done button. When I click the done button I want to perform some actions(like add some views) in the MainViewController according to the datas in the view that was returned from the ViewMaker class.
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your ViewMaker class is same as PopupContentMaker,

add this to your done button:

```
[done_button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

in PopupContenMaker:

```
- (void)doSomething{
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleDoneButtonTap)]) {
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(handleDoneButtonTap) withObject:self];
}

}
```

declare a delegate property in your PopupContentMaker, and make MainViewController the delegate,

```
-(void)GetContentView
{   
PopContentMaker *pcm = [[PopupContentMaker alloc] init];

pcm.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:[pcm GetContentView]];

}

-(void)handleDoneButtonTap{
//Do action after done button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[done_button addTarget: self
      action: @selector(buttonClickedMethod)
forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In this way you can call a custom method when button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the target and action as parameters to the getContentView method or you can use the delegate pattern.